# "Services" and "Files" tabs missing in NetBeans 7.1

Tags: netbeans

I've been using NetBeans for four months. One day, I removed the left panel where **Services**, **Files** and  **Project** appears as tabs. Also, there's a page structure just below the files.

Now I can see only the Project tab. How do I reset the windows to include the Files and Services tabs as well as the bottom file structure?

[image: See the current view of netbeans]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you should be able to click *Window*, and then enable your missing tabs again:

- Files
- Services
- Navigating » Navigator

[image]

Comment: thanks.. you saved my time..i was banging my head since 3 hrs.